Should I control for unit-specific linear time trends in difference-in-differences
I have a staggered difference-in-differences setup and have been wondering whether I should be including group/unit-specific linear time trends in my model.
It seems to be a common feature in the literature, yet there are papers that also argue these unit-specific time trends can lead to negative weighting and other issues.
Is there any consensus on when to/not to use unit-specific linear time trends in a difference-in-differences model?
Any overarching advice would be greatly appreciated!
